# How to display whether Cookie is just enabled or disabled?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript code shown below for displaying Cookies either

```
Enabled

or 

Disabled
```

Code is:

```
<script>
txt=navigator.cookieEnabled;
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;
</script>
```

But this code is just displaying

```
true
```

I have no idea how to go ahead.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may want refer to this link: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/cookiedetect.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`navigator.cookieEnabled` return `true` or `false`. So you can just display what you want on the basis of these values

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  txt=navigator.cookieEnabled;
  document.getElementById("example").innerText=(txt==true ?"Enabled":"Disabled");
</script>
```

Comment: are you doing something else other than this ? because it's working take a look http://jsfiddle.net/NryeR/

Answer (score 0):

please find the below link for checking the cookies enabled state:

http://sveinbjorn.org/cookiecheck

```
function are_cookies_enabled()
{
    var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

    if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled)
    { 
        document.cookie="testcookie";
        cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
    }
    return (cookieEnabled);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
txt=navigator.cookieEnabled;
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=(txt==true?"Enabled":"Disabled";
</script>
```